# Meaning of derivative in terms of the original function

Tags: derivatives

Let's say the distance for a car equals: $f(x) = 5x$. Then it's speed is $f'(x) = 5$. But what does it mean to have speed of five? So, for example speed of car at $t=10$ is $5$, but what does it mean?

Does it mean that distance will increase in 5 meters in the next second?
$f'(x) = f(x+1) - f(x) = f(11) - f(10) = 55 - 50 = 5 == 5$

Or does it mean that distance has increased in 5 meters in the last second?
$f'(x) = f(x) - f(x-1) = f(10) - f(9) = 50 - 45 = 5 == 5$

Okay, this explanation might work for a simple function but let's say $f(x) = x^2$ and it won't work anymore.

For example.

$f'(3)=2*3=6$

$f(x+1)-f(x) = f(4) - f(3) = 16 - 9 = 7 <> 6$

$f(x) - f(x-1) = f(3) - f(2) = 9 - 4 = 5 <> 6$

But what I noticed is that for the case $f(x) = x^2$ there is an other correlation: $f'(x) = (f(x+1) + f(x-1))/2 = (f(4) - f(2))/2 = (16-4)/2 = 6 == 6$.

But if we try it with $f(x) = x^3$ then this rule won't work anymore. What will work is $f'(x) - 1 = (f(x+1) + f(x-1))/2$.

For $f(x) = x^4$ it will be $f'(x) - 4*x = (f(x+1) + f(x-1))/2$.

So my questions are:

- what derivative mean in terms of $f(x)$? Like if $f'(x) = 5$ then what it can tell me about the change in $f(x)$? And why $f(x+1) <> f(x) + f'(x)$?
- whats the reasons behind the correlations i've found for $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$?

Comment: what does $<>$ mean?

Comment: $f'(x)$ means the __instant__ rate of change of $f(x)$, __not__ the change of a period of time.

Comment: 1 second would be $\Delta x$ not dx. dx is infinitely smaller. That's the whole point of calculus.

Comment: $<>$ means "not equals"

Comment: [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient) and [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) are linked but are not the same mathematical concept.

Comment: so, is it like $f(x+Δx) = f(x) + f'(x) *Δx$ is true when $Δx$ is infinitely small? And then if $f'(x) = 5$ and it is instant rate of change extrapolated to the $Δx = 1$? (like $f(x0+1) = f(x0) + f'(x0)$ is true if $f'(x)$ is constant for $x = x0..x0+1$)

Comment: If we want to make $|f(x)+f'(x)\cdot \Delta x - f(x+\Delta x)|$ small, then we can do this by taking small enough $\Delta x$. In other words, the error goes to $0$ for small enough $\Delta x$. "Infinitely small" is magic at this point, which makes everything "work".